# How do I use the Hide/Reveal Module in Joomla's sample content

Tags: joomla

Just found one in `/index.php/directions` example:

[image]

But can't find any suggestions on how to use it... May be someone where i can fine manual on this spoiler (module) ?

Comment: please explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve from from the information given, your "question" will most likely be closed

Comment: @cppl i need to find out how to use this spoiler.

Comment: @Kirix - are you referring to the module?

Comment: @Lodder no, i just simply need some example on spoiler like this http://docs.joomla.org/Using_the_JHtmlTabs_class_in_a_component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module you show in your screenshot is just a standard Joomla! "Custom HTML" module in the sample data set. There is no manual for it.

The "hide/reveal" mechanism is from the "Beez5" template, specifically it's created by the module chrome file. You can find that file in `/templates/beez5/html/modules.php` and the Javascript for it in `/templates/beez5/javascript/hide.js`.

Modules can have their default [chrome specified by the template](http://docs.joomla.org/Module_chrome), it's also possible to create [module layout over-rides](http://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides#Module_Layout_Overrides) for specific templates.